# Folding on Regex in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I use Pandoc when writing, and paste in html code for more complex tables.  This can make the file look untidy, and I would like to use Vim's foldexpr to fold these table elements using a regular expression.  This regular expression:

```
<table\b[^>]*>(?:(?=([^<]+))\1|<(?!table\b[^>]*>))*?</table>
```

works to highlight the table code in Sublime Text and BBEdit, but I don't seem able to get it to work in Vim (very much my editor of choice).

Looking at "Vim Scripting the Hardway", I was hoping to write a simple function like this:

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=GetTableFold(v:lnum)

```
function! GetTableFold(lnum)
    if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v<table\b[^>]*>(?:(?=([^<]+))\1|<(?!table\b[^>]*>))*?  </table>
    return '-1'
endif
return '0'
endfunction
```

in order to hide the table element in my file but it doesn't work.  When I try to do a simple search for the regex in Vim I also get a "E64: ? follows nothing" error.

Any ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: code syntax highlighting gives you hint.

Comment: Just prepending `\v` makes Vim regexps more like PCRE, but there are still differences; your `(?:...)` and `(?=...)` don't work this way in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues with the way you're doing this.  For one, you've got syntax issues with your regex (as Ingo pointed out).  Also, I think you don't quite understand how vim calculates the fold levels.  Vim calls your function "GetTableFold" once for every line in the file.  This then returns a foldlevel for that specific line.  Because you have no context other than the line number you can't just match the line to a regex that spans multiple lines.  Instead, you have to calculate whether or not your line falls in this range manually.

I haven't written any vimscript in a while so this may be a bit buggy but it seems to work in the few simple cases I tried.  At the very least it should give you a base of where to start.

```
function GetTableFold(lnum)
    let n = a:lnum
    while n > 0
        let currline = getline(n)
        let prevline = getline(n-1)
        if currline =~ '\v\<table\>|\<\/table\>'
            return '1'
        elseif currline =~ '\v^\s*$'
            " special case for blank lines
            return '-1'
        elseif prevline =~ '\v\<\/table\>'
            " special case for the line after </table>
            return '0'
        endif
        let n -= 1
    endwhile
    return '0'
endfunction

set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=GetTableFold(v:lnum)
```

This makes some nasty (reasonable?) assumptions such as you will never have `<table>` and `</table>` on the same line.  Given your use case of only putting complex tables in your pandoc files I think this is a safe assumption.  It does not handle tables within tables too well.  If you need that you'll have to tweak this a bit.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Randy, leaving in the special case for blank lines seems to lead to unpredictable results, so I removed this and ensure that the table code doesn't contain any.  Works perfectly then.